# Bootstrap: offset column content not centered and wrapping issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/17194/

I want 8 columns to be centered in the middle of the page but I'm having trouble actually getting it to stay in the middle and wrap properly when used at different device sizes.

Below is the relevant code for this part of the website. The wrapping issue with the text is shown in the large breakpoint I believe, and by the medium breakpoint things look fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Zac Litwinchuk : About</title>
<meta name="author" content="name">
<meta name="description" content="description here">
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
<script defer src="js\fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light">


<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 my-3 px-0 ">
<h2>Get In Touch</h2>
<p>Please feel free to contact me via the below form</p>
<p>Do not hesitate to contact me via social media. My social media links are in the footer section of my website.</p>
<p>A downloadable version of my resume is available at the below link.</p>
<a class="btn btn-success text-light">Download My Resume</a>
</div>

<hr>

<form class="offset-md-2 my-3 ">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
<label>Your Message</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
</form>



  <footer class="row bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-2 mb-1">
      <p> ©  | 2018</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 text-right mt-2 mb-1">
      <a class="text-light" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x mr-1"></i></a>
      <a class="text-light" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x mr-1"></i></a>
    </div>
  </footer>


  </div>


<script src="js\jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js\typewriter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Without `.row` in place your `.col-*-*` will always be slightly off.  The row wrapper is necessary for adjusting the margin.

Comment: ahh ok... i missed that I forgot .row. should i wrap the div with the text in it with another div with .row? Not sure if putting .col together with .row would work in this case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try making your `col-md-10` a `col-md-8` and see if thats better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to your desired result but there are some structural errors in your approach.  You haven't wrapped your `.col-*-*` inside the `.row` element which will always result in your columns being slightly 'wrong' in their layout.  The other issue is that `offset-*-*` applies to both the left and right right.  So `offset-md-2` actually means "Offset this column by 2 on the left, and 2 on the right".

A minimal approach demonstrating your desired layout would look something like the below code.  I've added classes to show/hide certain text at various breakpoints so you can see how it would adjust:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
      <div class="bg-success p-4 text-light d-block d-md-none  d-lg-none"><strong class="mr-2">XS:</strong>I am 12 columns with no offset.</div>
      <div class="bg-danger p-4 text-light d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><strong class="mr-2">MD:</strong>I am 10 columns with 1 offset left and right.</div>
      <div class="bg-info p-4 text-light d-none d-lg-block"><strong class="mr-2">LG:</strong>I am 8 columns with 2 offset left and right.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll need to expand the snippet to view all the breakpoints so you can see how `offset` works in conjunction with `col`.

Comment: I need to clarify one misleading sentence in my answer; `offset-*-*` only pushes from the left, it's just that when using it to *center* a grid item you have to consider that you need an equal gap on the right.  The way I wrote my answer sounds like it applies an offset on either side.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
`col-md-10 mx-auto` instead of `col-md-10 offset-md-2 my-3 px-0`